# Visual Studio_BreakPoints

Tags: visual-studio, breakpoints

I am using Visual Studio Community 2017.

I want to do some debugging of the code using break-points.

From my research there is supposed to be a "red dot" showing the breakpoint when you click on the far left of the bar (prior to your code).

For some reason it is not showing.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Wow, it has been quite a day.

You need to left click in the far left pane (all the way next to the window) and that will put your breakpoints in.
-SC